# Proof by Induction problem. Unsure of sigma notation.

Tags: calculus, induction

I want to use proof by induction to verify 
$$\sum_{j=n}^{2n-1} (2j+1) = 3n^2.$$

First I assume that the expression is valid for some number k,
 $S(k) = 2k + 1 $

Then k + 1 so that,  $S(k+1) = s(k) + a(k+1) = 3k^2 + (2(k+1)+1) = 3k^2 + 2k +3 $

However, if I try to insert j = k + 1 into the sum-formula $ 3n^2 $ it equals $3(k+1)^2= 3k^2 + 6k +3 $. Which is not the same. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check the base case.  For $n=1$ you get $3=3$, which is correct.  For the inductive step, you are not writing clearly.  What do you mean by $S(k)=2k+1?$  Your assumption should be that the equality is true for $k$, then prove the $k+1$ case, so $$\sum_{j=k}^{2k-1} (2j+1) = 3k^2\\\sum_{j=k+1}^{2k+1} (2j+1) = 3k^2-(2k+1)+(4k+1+4k+3)$$ Where the subtraction comes because we deleted the $k$ term from the sum and the addition because we added the $2k$ and $2k+1$ terms to the sum