# Induction proof that $\sum_{j=n}^{2n-1} (2j + 1) = 3n^2$ - what happened?

Tags: calculus, induction

So I have the general summation formula that I was to prove using mathemathical induction on a Calculus level.

For all $n = {1,2,3,...}$ we have:

$$\sum_{j=n}^{2n-1} (2j + 1) = 3n^2$$

In the answer, the one completing the proof gets this, on the $n=k+1$:

$$\sum_{j=(k+1)}^{2(k+1)-1} (2j + 1) = \sum_{j=k}^{2k-1} (2j + 1) - (2k+1) + (4k+1) + (4k+3)$$

$$= 3k^2 + 6k + 3 = 3(k+1)^2$$

Can anyone explain how on earth this was done? When I tried, I was unable to factorize - I tried by adding the $(2(k+1)+1)$ to the $S_n$ formula and thereby confirm it, but I couldn't do it...

Comment: in this summation the lower limit increases by one each time, so you have to subtract the term  that drops out as well as adding the two new ones

Comment: That's fine, but how do you get $2(k+1)-1 = 2k+2-1 = 2k+1$ to be $2k-1$?

Comment: don't get bogged down (easy to do!). suggest you first try writing out the actual sum for small values of k, say k=3, 4 and 5. that should help you get a handle on it, then go back and try the algebra again

Comment: The base question is the same as in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604804/proof-by-induction-problem-unsure-of-sigma-notation/604813#604813)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare the sums

$$\sum_{j=k+1}^{2(k+1)-1}(2j+1)=\sum_{j=k+1}^{2k+1}(2j+1)\tag{1}$$

and

$$\sum_{j=k}^{2k-1}(2j+1)\;,\tag{2}$$

the first being the one that you want to evaluate, the second being the one whose value you know. The first sum does not have a $j=k$ term; the second one does. The first sum **does** have a $j=2k$ term and a $j=2k+1$ term; the second does not. To convert $(2)$ into $(1)$, therefore, you must subtract the $j=k$ term and add in the extra $j=2k$ and $j=2k+1$ terms.

The $j=k$ term is $2k+1$; you need to subtract that, because it’s not included in $(1)$. The $j=2k$ and $j=2k+1$ terms are $2(2k)+1=4k+1$ and $2(2k+1)+1=4k+3$; you need to add those, because they’re included in $(1)$ but are not already present in $(2)$. Thus,

$$\sum_{j=k+1}^{2k+1}(2j+1)=\sum_{j=k}^{2k-1}(2j+1)-(2k+1)+(4k+1)+(4k+3)\;,$$

and since $(4k+1)+(4k+3)-(2k+1)=6k+3$, we have

$$\sum_{j=k+1}^{2k+1}(2j+1)=\sum_{j=k}^{2k-1}(2j+1)+6k+3\;,$$

The induction hypothesis is that $(2)$ is $3n^2$, so this simplifies further to

$$\sum_{j=k+1}^{2k+1}(2j+1)=3n^2+6k+3=3(n^2+2n+1)=3(n+1)^2\;.\;,$$

Comment: Thank you so much for being so thorough!

Comment: One question: Is it possible to do this using the $S_n = 3n^2$. We then remove $a_0$ and add $a_{k+1}$? I imagine it'd be the same.

Comment: @Erlend: You’re welcome! As for the question, this is doing it with $S_n=3n^2$, but the adjustment from $S_n$ to $S_{n+1}$ isn’t subtracting $a_0$ and adding $a_{n+1}$: it’s subtracting $a_n$ and adding $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$.

Comment: Ahh.. I get it now. Cheers mate. Was just all the tampering with the limits of the sum that really threw me off. Keep doing math inside a small box and it eventually becomes an entire universe of walls, eh

Comment: @Erlend: :-) Sometimes it’s helpful to write out the first few and the last few terms, just to make sure that you see what’s going on.

Answer (score 0):

The boundaries of the summation were 2k+1 and k+1, so by extracting the last 2 terms and adding a new first term, the boundaries change to k and 2k-1. He then subs in the assumption, expands/simplifies then factor out the three to make a perfect square